# How to display the restricted rows in ListView

Tags: javafx-2

I have taken the horizontal list view.I am able to display the images in list view.It is displaying all the images horizontally.But my requirement is i need to show only 4 images in a row.If there is 5th image then it should come in the second row(for each row there should me only 4 images).How can i do this.Actually i am struck up here.I think you are able to understand my problem.Thank You.

I am using JavaFX 2.x

Comment: Are you trying to implement a "thumbnails view"?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, if you need to allocate only 4 images in a row, and the 5th+ images transfer on the next row, you will be able to use a GridPane :

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

where you could obviously set position of ImageView. Seems, it works so : you determine your own ListCell, and set its graphic node to be a gridpane, and configure grid pane as you wish.

Also, take a look on a flow pane, possibly, it will help you.

If I'm wrong with a recipe, please, try to describe your trouble again (code/screenshot). I'm not comletely sure about it.